# Can't import library to project

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, orange

I try to create project in Python, which is composed of GAE, Django and [Orange library](http://orange.biolab.si/). When I create this project without Orange there is no problem to run it. But when I attach that library to project i get message

```
ImportError: No module named orange
```

I try to add sources to my project directory but it also doesn't work. I try to create project in Eclipse and in PyCharm - still the same error. But, when I write instruction

`from orange import...`

intellisense works properly. I would be aprecciate if someone could help me import this lib into my project :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAE does not support python modules with C extensions. In their own words:

> Application code written for the Python environment must be written exclusively in Python. Extensions written in the C language are not supported.

- http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html

---

```
$ cloc Orange-2.0.0b/
    1625 text files.
    1508 unique files.                                          
     305 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.53  T=5.0 s (251.4 files/s, 62502.0 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python                         714          25736          24393          90413
C++         <-- !!!            125          16505           5423          61998
HTML                           235           8643             95          29406
C                               22           2436           5794          14876
C/C++ Header                   134           5982           4497          13878
CSS                              6            318             81           1373
make                            10             81             23            318
Javascript                       1             14             52             91
SQL                              5              5              5             50
DOS Batch                        5              3              1             20
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                          1257          59723          40364         212423
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I had the same problem.  Your answer is not clear to me.  Could you please elaborate.  I understand that you say application code written for the Python environments should be in Python.  How do we solve this?  I have installed Orange on windows.  I have the same problem even using ubuntu.  Please let me know.  Thanks for your help in advance.